# Display User Friendly number in URL instead of GUID in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

Is there any way to Hide Guid from Url and display some User Friendly number.
Like

```
localhost:49519/Info/0b16c74f-596c-e311-8b83-6c626da99cc2
```

should display like

```
localhost:49519/Info/012477454412
```

I have searched a lot but only possible solution that i found to use routing. but in place of Info/{id} in route, i have to pass Guid as my Id. is there any way not to show GUID In url?

Thank You.

Comment: A guid contains 128 bits of information (okay, so if you're only dealing with one type of guid you can omit a few of those bits). So if you need the full range that guids represent, you need to represent all of those bits. You could use a slightly shorter string format e.g. use the N format, or format the data in base 64 instead (`T8cWC2xZEeOLg2xibamcwg==`).

Comment: or use an int or string parameter like you have (012477...), and link that to the actual guid in a database.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i have thousands of records with this type of Guid. i need to handles records as well. can't we replace this Guid with any shorter random number in Url, But internally it will use actual Guid.

Comment: Your example shorter number is 12 digits long. 12 digits can only encode ~40 bits.

Comment: Yes @ps2goat,i thought somthing like same.i thought there might be somthing to handle situations like this in MVC, whch are not known to me. 
Addding a new column with auto increment and showing that in url that will be last option .